# Using <<< throws error on sh shell not in bash

Tags: bash, sh, sunos

In Sh

```
[SunOs] /opt # sh
[\h] \w \$ read -a array <<< "1 2 3";echo ${array[1]}
syntax error: `<' unexpected
```

In Bash

```
[SunOs] ~ # bash
[SunOs] ~ # read -a array <<< "1 2 3";echo ${array[1]}
2
```

Why the Error thorwn in "sh" shell, i'm using SunOS 5.10 Generic_147440-10 sun4v sparc sun4v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Herestrings aren't supported in `sh`.

This causes the error when you try to run it using `sh`.

Comment: Thanks it's not supported in SunOs, i can run the same command in Linux and MacOSX it works

Comment: @anish Moreover `read` available with `sh` wouldn't support `-a`.

Comment: @anish: `sh` is not `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you may use the builtin POSIX command `set` to assign your arguments to the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, ... or the positional parameter array `$@` respectively

```
{
IFS="`printf ' \n\t'`"
export IFS
printf '%s' "$IFS" | od -b
set -- `printf '%s' "1 2 3"`
echo "$0"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
echo "$@"
}
```